# How can I search last.fm for tracks that have two specific tags?

Tags: last.fm

Let's say I want to find music on [last.fm](http://last.fm) that is tagged with both `trance` and `new wave`.

Is this possible?

So far I can only figure out how to browse by single tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is currently in the Last.fm playground;

http://playground.last.fm/multitag

> Welcome to Last.fm's playground! Here you can try out some of the projects we are working on and let us know what you think.

Hope this helps

Comment: Link no longer works and there's no alternative I can find